# Returning data from Ajax call in Ext.onReady

Tags: javascript, ajax, extjs

I have an Ext JS app and I want to check on the backend if the session is invalid every time a user clicks on a link within the app. These two Ajax calls are both in Ext.onReady, I would like to clean up this code but I need to check for timeout every click, the second Ajax call is only called upon logging in if it were by itself.

```
Ext.Ajax.on('requestcomplete', function(conn, response, options, options) {
    if(!isSessionValid()) {
        window.location.href = '?login_status=timeout';
    }
});

function isSessionValid() {
    Ext.Ajax.request({
        url: contextRoot + '/isSessionValid.htm?alt=json',
        method: 'get',
        success: function(response, options) {
            console.log(response);
            var isValid;
            var o = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
            (o != loggedInUser.username) ? isValid = false : isValid = true;
            return isValid;
        }, failure: function(response, options) {
            //console.log(response);
        }
    });
};
```

Is there a work around to not have isSessionValid() be undefined and get the data I need (isValid)?

Comment: Your code doesn't really make sense. `isSessionValid` will always return `undefined`.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli yes.. is there a work around?

Comment: Run a callback function when the request completes. But also your requests will run infinitely, because when a request completes you trigger another request.

Comment: move the redirect part into the `success` function of the Ajax request, but as Evan said: you will create a infinite loop.